# How to change status bar color in iOS8 extension?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

`UIApplication` is not allowed inside extension, `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in `UIViewController` are ignored. Any other ideas?

Comment: My extension is full screen with dark background, so the black status bar text isn't enough visible, same can happen when someone have app with white status bar text and extension with default navigation bar. Also  Apple extensions (Mail) don't have problem with changing status bar.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe use the Info.plist?

Comment: No, i tried both UIStatusBarStyle and UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

Comment: I found confirmation elsewhere that this is a known issue. You inherit the host's status bar settings and there's nothing you can do about it. I suggest filing a bug report.